# 3-ary relationship with composite foreign keys using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We have three entities involved in this problem. For simplicity, let's name them A, B, C. Each of them has its own identifier as the primary key.

[image: ER diagram]

The 3-ary relationship adds some other fields we are skipping for simplicity. It has the following constraints:

- A previous relation between A and C must exist
- A previous relation between A and B must exist
- The entity A (its id) must be the same

In terms of database schema:

```
create table a_b_c
(
    a_id   int,
    b_id   int,
    c_id   int,
    primary key (a_id, r_id, c_id),
    constraint fk_a_c foreign key (a_id, c_id) references c (a_id, id) on delete cascade,
    constraint fk_a_b foreign key (a_id, b_id) references a_b (a_id, b_id) on delete cascade
)
```

I've tried the following classes:

```
public class A {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(name = "a_b",
              inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id"))
   private List<B> bs;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a", orphanRemoval = true) 
   private List<C> cs;

}

public class B {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;

   //I don't need to access A from B objects

}

public class C {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;

   @ManyToOne
   private A a;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "c", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   private List<ABC> abcs;

}

@Embeddable
public class ABCId {

    @Column(name = "a_id")
    private Integer aId;

    @Column(name = "b_id")
    private Integer bId;

    @Column(name = "c_id")
    private Integer cId;
}

public class ABC {

    @EmbeddedId
    protected ABCId id = new ABCId();

    @MapsId("aId")
    @ManyToOne
    private A a;

    @MapsId("bId")
    @ManyToOne
    private B b;

    @MapsId("cId")
    @ManyToOne
    private C c;

}
```

When the application tries to create a new instance of type A, when creating ABC on cascade, it fails because of the constraints in the database schema (shown above): the entries relating to A and C, and A and B do not exist in the database yet. It also fails when trying to update or delete.

I think JPA does not know anything about the constraints existing in the database, so I must be missing how to describe those constraints in the classes.

My solution right now is to create the needed entries by using specific repositories instead of relying entirely on the A class.

So my questions are:

- Does the design of the classes reflect the constraints in the database schema?
- If not, how can I describe such constraints using JPA?

Thank you in advance.